# Cannot map entities. Fetching one entity gives columns of second entity in first entity columns

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, oracle11g

I am trying to fetch entity using Hibernate and JPA. But fetching one entity tries to find columns of second entity in the first entity. here's code:

I have two entities:

Entity1.java

```
@Id
@Column(name = "WRITE_PROTECTION_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = FrontendDBTableSequenceNm.WRITE_PROTECTION_ID_SEQ)
@SequenceGenerator(name = FrontendDBTableSequenceNm.WRITE_PROTECTION_ID_SEQ,
sequenceName = FrontendDBTableSequenceNm.WRITE_PROTECTION_ID_SEQ, allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

/** The division. */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DIVISION_ID")
private Entity2 entity2;
```

Entity2.java

```
@Id
@Column(name = "DIVISION_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = FrontendDBTableSequenceNm.DIVISION_ID_SEQ)
@SequenceGenerator(name = FrontendDBTableSequenceNm.DIVISION_ID_SEQ, 
sequenceName =  FrontendDBTableSequenceNm.DIVISION_ID_SEQ, allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

/** The name. */
@Column(name = "DIVISION_NM")
@ChangeLog
private String name;

/** The sort order. */
@Column(name = "SORT_ORDER")
@ChangeLog
private Integer sortOrder;

/** The markets. */
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "division")
private Set<Market> markets;

/** The company. */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CMPNY_ID")
private Company company;
```

Now when I try to fetch entity one in using repository :

```
@Query("from Entity1 wp order by wp.entity2.name")
List<WriteProtection> findAllOrderByDivision();
```

the query that hits the database is :

```
select entity0_.ENTITY_1_ID as WRITE1_20_, 
entity0_.CREATE_BY as CREATE2_20_, 
entity0_.CREATE_TMS as CREATE3_20_, 
entity0_.UPD_BY as UPD4_20_, 
entity0_.UPD_TMS as UPD5_20_, 
entity0_.ENTITY2_ID as ENTITY27_20_, 
entity0_.TREE_LEVEL as TREE6_20_ 
from rmc_dev_rel3.ENTITY_1 entity0_, rmc_dev_rel3.ENTITY2 ENTITY21_ 
where entity0_.ENTITY2_ID=ENTITY21_.ENTITY2_ID order by ENTITY21_.ENTITY2_NM;
```

So basically what it is doing is it is trying to find columns of second entity in first entity.

As in here columns "CREATE_BY", "CREATE_TMS", "UPD_BY" and "UPD_TMS" are columns in entity2, but query is trying to fetch it from entity1.

Comment: Try to change query like @Query("Select wp from Entity1 wp order by wp.entity2.name")

Comment: @Ramesh it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the query to the following solved my issue :

```
@Query("select wp.id, wp.entity2, wp.treeLevel from Entity1 wp order by wp.entity2.name")
```